# Jruby: NameError: uninitialized constant Neo4j

Tags: ruby, macos, jruby, neo4j

I ran this example from git: https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j

```
require "rubygems"
require 'neo4j'

Neo4j::Transaction.run do
  node = Neo4j::Node.new(:name => 'andreas')
  node.outgoing(:friends) << Neo4j::Node.new(:name => 'peter')
  node.outgoing(:friends).each {|node| puts "name #{node[:name]}"}
end
```

and it outputted the error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Neo4j
  const_missing at org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2626
         (root) at ./neo4j.rb:4
        require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
        require at ./neo4j.rb:36
         (root) at /Users/ZATLUKE/RubymineProjects/nokogiri/neo4j.rb:2
           load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1052
         (root) at -e:1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of `neo4j` and which version of `activesupport` do you have installed?

Comment: Neo4j 1.3.1 and activesupport 3.2.1, on jruby 1.6.6[1.9]

Comment: I guess your environment is broken. In IRB what does require "neo4j" return, and Neo4j::VERSION ? Btw 1.3.1 does not work with active support 3.2.x try 3.1 instead.

Comment: Perhaps upgrade Andeas R's comment to an answer, to give him some SO karma?

Comment: Sorry, I totally gave up on it. Not sure how to upgrade a comment to an answer. But I'll bump him.

Comment: IRB is interactive ruby shell, for those who had to look that up.