# JRuby and Neo4j scaffold generation error (OS X)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, neo4j, jrubyonrails

I am following the Rails and Neo4j tutorial http://blog.jayway.com/2011/03/02/neo4j-rb-1-0-0-and-rails-3/ and get the following errors:

```
me$ rails generate scaffold post title:string body:string
LoadError: no such file to load -- active_support/core_ext/class/inheritable_attributes
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
   (root) at /Users/me/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/neo4j-1.3.1-java/lib/neo4j.rb:9
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
   (root) at /Users/me/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.5/gems/neo4j-1.3.1-java/lib/neo4j.rb:8
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
   (root) at /Users/me/Projects/myblog/config/application.rb:24
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
   (root) at script/rails:6
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383118/jruby-nameerror-uninitialized-constant-neo4j, I have activesupport 3.1 installed as well as v3.2.3.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using version 1.x of Neo4j.rb which does not work with rails 3.2+.
Either use rails 3.1 or use neo4j.rb version 2.0.0.alpha.9+
Also, check the demo application using 2.0.0.alpha.9 and scaffolding - https://github.com/andreasronge/kvitter